# can't boot from usb

Tags: boot

Trying to boot into Ubuntu from a USB stick. Got all the files on the USB, and set BIOS to look at USB first. When I turn it on, the light flashes on my USB, so I know it's accessing it. It brings up the first screen of Ubuntu--the screen shows the word Ubuntu, the logo, and five dots under the word Ubuntu, but then it hangs up there. Doesn't progress at all. Ideas?

Comment: What's the make and model of your machine? What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?